# Gradle build can't find method

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm following through the [Start Developing for Android](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/android-start-developing) course in Pluralsight.  We're just about to add tests.  The instructions say to add add `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'` to the `build.gradle` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 

all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
  }
}
```

After doing this IntelliJ tells me that as the Gradle file has changed, it needs to sync again.  When I do it though I get the following error:

Error:

```
15:17   Gradle sync failed: Could not find method androidTestCompile() for arguments [com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

NB:  I tried versions `2.2.1` and `2.2.2`.

What's going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency should be added to the `build.gradle` of the `app` module. In your case you added to the `build.gradle` of parent project.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I've got a follow up question as I'm getting another error now, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399724/cannot-find-androidtestcompile-on-android-build).  Would you be able to have a look at that one too?  Thanks.