# Cannot find androidTestCompile on Android build

Tags: java, android, mobile, intellij-idea

Following on from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398891/gradle-build-cant-find-method/41398937#41398937), which is resolved.

I'm following through the [Start Developing for Android](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/android-start-developing) course in Pluralsight.  We're just about to add tests.  The instructions say to add add `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'` to the `build.gradle` file (the one in the `app` module).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.sqisland.android.hello'
    minSdkVersion 1
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.0'
  }

  dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
  }
}
```

When I sync the build I can an error though:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 8 declared in library [com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2] F:\BanksySan\Development\PluralSight\android-hello-world\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test.espresso\espresso-core\2.2.2\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.espresso" to force usage
```

Should I use the suggested fix?  At the moment I'm thinking that's it's more likely that I'm missing a library somewhere.

**After Andy's suggestion below**

I've moved the block outside, the error is:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 8 declared in library [com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2] F:\BanksySan\Development\PluralSight\android-hello-world\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test.espresso\espresso-core\2.2.2\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.espresso" to force usage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `dependencies` block out of `android` block and raise your `minSdkVersion` to at least `8`:

```
android {  
   minSdkVersion: 8  
   //... 
}

dependencies {   
   // .... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy.  I've just done that, but still an exception.

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem is that you have your `minSdkVersion = 1`. 1?! but the espresso lib min sdk version is 8. You can apply the suggested fix (`tools:overrideLibrary`), but are you sure you want your min sdk version to be 1? this is no longer supported. I would suggest to have it 14, or if you are aiming for backward compatibility then you can have 8.

Comment: Yes, that's it.  Odd, the example file in the video uses `minSdkVersion` 1.  I wonder how the speaker is making it work.  Anyhow, thanks for you help.  It's most appreciated.